# I cannot connect javascript function with html <input> tags and onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, http

Hi I am working on a website and i stumbbled across an annoying thing. I cannot, for the love of anything, get to work my form to be able to do some maths and insert them into  tag.

P.S nothing works for me, even GetElementsById... or other callouts :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function price(this.form){

                var amount = form.elements[1].value;
                var gold_price = 0.17;
                var price_calc = 0;

                price_calc = (amount/gold_price) + " M";
                window.alert("price_calc");
                form.elements[5].value = price_calc;
                }
</script>
```

//this is input that i would like to get a number to work with in the function

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="amount" value="10" onchange="price(this.form)" onclick="price(this.form)" maxlength="4" required/>
</div>
```

//this is input I would like to write in in after function is done functioning :)

```
<input type="text" id="total_price" placeholder="Total:"/>
```

thanks for any help in advance.

thanks again,...

Comment: Have you checked your dev console?

Comment: Are your html elements actually in a form?

Comment: You should put all the code related to the form, that is, the form and all the code inside it.

Comment: every input i have in <div> tags are in form... i forgot to type it sry :)

Comment: @lumio im programming my website in pure notepad++ :)

Comment: If I were you I would watch a few more javascript tutirals. You are stuck in some basic stuff, e.g. `function price(this.form)` has wrong syntax. That way you save your time.

Comment: @Timon that was not what I meant. [Read this stackoverflow question/answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) on how to use your browsers dev console for debugging

Comment: I agree with @deathangel908. Start with looking at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange2  then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `price` function to receive an `input` parameter. Actually `this.form` as parameter is an invalid statement and leads to an error.

Instead pass `this` (inside your `on*` property) and select the input value.

```js
// select #total_price
const totalPrice = document.getElementById( 'total_price' );

function price( input ) {
  // Convert value to a number
  var amount = +input.value;
  var gold_price = 0.17;
  var price_calc = 0;

  price_calc = ( amount / gold_price ) + " M";
  totalPrice.value = price_calc;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amount" value="10" oninput="price( this )" onclick="price( this )" maxlength="4" required/>
<br>
<input type="text" id="total_price" placeholder="Total:" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This code working:

```
<input type="text" value="10" oninput="price(this)" maxlength="4" />
<input type="text" id="total_price" placeholder="Total:" />
<script>
    function price(el){

        var amount = parseInt(el.value);
        var gold_price = 0.17;
        var price_calc = (amount / gold_price) + " M";

        window.alert("Total: " + price_calc);
        document.getElementById('total_price').value = "Total: " + price_calc;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you that worked.. and thanks to all the others that helped... i will look more tutorials :) thanks again David